# Rails: Access model from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this question been ask before and they said 'models are independent of the controller.' So, following my same code I did for other models I just renamed my working code to fit to my new model. But I'm getting an error `undefined method 'userimages_path'` Here the code I'm using.

The model is `userimage` and the controller is `uploads`.

Controller/uploads_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @userimage = Userimage.new
  end
```

Model/userimage.rb is an empty file

Views/uploads/new.html.erb (This line is throwing the error.)

```
  <%= form_for @userimage do |f|%>
```

In my routes.rb

```
resources :uploads
```

I have `rake db:migrate` several times to make sure I did migrate the database thinking this might be why it can't find the `Userimage`.

What I have I done wrong/missing here?

Comment: can you show your schema file / migration that covers user image?

Comment: Can you confirm your model is `Userimage` compared to `UserImage`?

Comment: `create_table "userimages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end`

Comment: I looked at the model and every other file and it i Userimages not UserImages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Rails magic, when you don't specify second option(`url`) for `form_for`, Rails try to set it, in your case `<%= form_for @userimage do |f|%>` converts by Rails to `<%= form_for @userimage, url: userimages_path do |f|%>`, in your routes, there is no such `_path` helper. 
To resolve this issue run `bundle rake routes` and set the right `url` option.

[`Check the documentation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Comment: To me, Rails is alien technology. I'm impress to how much it automatically does things for me and it just works with less code.  .... Oh, oh! My light bulb just came on! So rails was routing according to the model/crud not controller/crud?..interesting. It works!! I was mystify why it was looking for userimages_path. Thought it was smart enough to route to new_uploads in the form_for so I didn't think to look there! Marked as answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

## view

```
 <%= form_for @userimage, url: "/uploads" do |f|%>
```

## uploads controller

```
def create
  ...
end
```